# How to make changes on firebase database triggered by remote config?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, eventtrigger, firebase-remote-config

So I have the following situation where It's hard to make a specific question besause I don't really know very well what my options are:
I have an Android App where I have "servers" to represent subjects, I want to change these subjects from time to time (I intend to use remote config for that) but I also need some kind of trigger so every time I change a subject the correspondent server get "cleaned". The better way I can think of is that I need to change the values directly on database. So tha question is... How to access and change values on db from a change on remote config? I accept any other suggestion

[image: ilustration]

Answer (score 0):

Changes in Remote Config are limited to just that product.  There is no simple configuration to have those changes reach out to other products.

What you can do instead is use a [Cloud Functions Remote Config trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/rc-events) to have run some backend code that you write to make changes to the database.  A full set of instructions to do this is outside the scope of a Stack Overflow answer, so I suggest you start with the [documentation for Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) to understand what it does and how to get started writing triggers for Remote Config changes.

Comment: it seems beautiful, I'll certainlly read about it. but just to clarify. I would still need to use the forebase triggers to change the subjects, right? Because it must be done manually, so these trigger would call the function. Did I get it right?

Comment: If you want a change in Remote Config to automatically and immediately propagate to some other product or destination, you will have to use Cloud Functions to make that happen.